# What is this "=>" in the use of properties?

Tags: c#, properties

Can someone explain to me what these code snippets do?

```html
class Pirat
{
        public string Name => "Jack";
}
```

```html
class Pirat
{
  private string _name;

  public string Name
  {
    get => _name;
    set => Name = value;
            
  }
}
```

These code examples are not in the same code

Answer (score 0):

"New" (actually quite old by now) syntax to define properties (and methods actually) with Lambda's.

The => should have been a hint - that is the same that is used in any other Lambda setup in C# (like LINQ).